# deadlock in SpringMVC with EhCache

Tags: spring, multithreading, ehcache

In the last two or three days, a website deployed on our tomcat service found a thread deadlock issue.After troubleshooting and analysis the JVM thread dump,we found a large thread blocks in  work thread and this problem may be caused by ehcache.
However, I believe that the usage of our ehcache is correct, can anyone help me to analyze the reasons?

The code and configuration of our program, log and other information is as follows,Thanks:

version：ehcache 2.10.3
         ehcache-core 2.6.11
         shiro-ehcache 1.2.4

src code:

```
@Service

public class UserBuslinesService {
    @Resource
    UserBuslinesDao userbuslinesDao;

    public List<UserBuslines> find(Map paraMap) {
        return userbuslinesDao.find(paraMap);
    }
    @Cacheable(value={"UserBuslines"}, key = "#map")
    public List<UserBuslines> select(Map map) {
        List<UserBuslines> oList = userbuslinesDao.select(map);
        return oList;
    }



    public List<UserBuslines> selectAll(Map map) {
        List<UserBuslines> oList = userbuslinesDao.selectAll(map);
        return oList;
    }

    public UserBuslines get(Serializable id) {
        return userbuslinesDao.get(id);
    }

    @CacheEvict(value={"UserBuslines", "CarInfoTree"}, allEntries=true)
    public void insert(UserBuslines entity) {
        userbuslinesDao.insert(entity);
    }

    @CacheEvict(value={"UserBuslines", "CarInfoTree"}, allEntries=true)
    public void update(UserBuslines entity) {
        userbuslinesDao.update(entity);
    }

    @CacheEvict(value={"UserBuslines", "CarInfoTree"}, allEntries=true)
    public void deleteById(Serializable id) {
        userbuslinesDao.deleteById(id);
    }

    @CacheEvict(value={"UserBuslines", "CarInfoTree"}, allEntries=true)
    public void deleteByIds(Map paraMap) {
        userbuslinesDao.deleteByIds(paraMap);
    }
    @CacheEvict(value={"UserBuslines", "CarInfoTree"}, allEntries=true)
    public void delete(Serializable[] ids) {
        userbuslinesDao.delete(ids);
    }
}


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/SelectLastestGpsData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Object> SelectLastestGpsData(Integer[] firstCorp, Integer[] corpIdList, Integer[] buslineIdList, String[] simNoList, HttpSession session) {
        List<LastestGpsData> lastestGpsDataList;
        List<CarInfoTree> carInfoTreeList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Object> key = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            {
                put("platforms", Arrays.asList(platform.replaceAll(" ", "").split(",")));
            }
        };

        Object cacheByCarTree = EhcacheUtil.getInstance().get("CarInfoTree", key);
        if (cacheByCarTree != null) {
            carInfoTreeList = (List<CarInfoTree>) cacheByCarTree;
        }
        Map<String, Object> queryUserBuslinesMap = new HashMap<>();
        queryUserBuslinesMap.put("userId", session.getAttribute("UserId"));
        List<UserBuslines> userBuslinesList = userBuslinesService.select(queryUserBuslinesMap);


        List<CarInfoTree> targetCarInfoList = carInfoTreeList
                .stream()
                .filter(
                        e -> (firstCorp != null && Arrays.asList(firstCorp).contains(e.getParentId())) ||
                                (corpIdList != null && Arrays.asList(corpIdList).contains(e.getCorpId())) ||
                                (buslineIdList != null && Arrays.asList(buslineIdList).contains(e.getBuslineId())) ||
                                (simNoList != null && Arrays.asList(simNoList).contains(e.getSimNo()))
                ).filter(car -> userBuslinesList.stream().anyMatch(ub -> ub.getBuslineId() == car.getBuslineId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        lastestGpsDataList = selectLastestGpsData(targetCarInfoList);


        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("rows", lastestGpsDataList);
        if(lastestGpsDataList.size()>0){
            //EhcacheUtil.getInstance().put("gnssData", session.getAttribute("UserId"), lastestGpsDataList);
            storageHashMap.put(session.getAttribute("UserId"), lastestGpsDataList);
        }

        return result;
    }
-------------------------------------------------------
public class EhcacheUtil {
    private static final String path = "/ehcache-config.xml";

    private URL url;

    private CacheManager manager;

    private static EhcacheUtil ehCache;

    private EhcacheUtil(String path) {
        url = getClass().getResource(path);
        manager = CacheManager.create(url);
    }

    public static EhcacheUtil getInstance() {
        if (ehCache== null) {
            ehCache= new EhcacheUtil(path);
        }
        return ehCache;
    }

    public void put(String cacheName, Object key, Object value) {
        Cache cache = manager.getCache(cacheName);
        Element element = new Element(key, value);
        cache.put(element);
        cache.flush();
    }

    public Object get(String cacheName, Object key) {
        Cache cache = manager.getCache(cacheName);
        Element element = cache.get(key);
        return element == null ? null : element.getObjectValue();
    }

    public Cache get(String cacheName) {
        return manager.getCache(cacheName);
    }

    public void remove(String cacheName, String key) {
        Cache cache = manager.getCache(cacheName);
        cache.remove(key);
    }
}
```

thread dump:

```
"http-nio-6600-exec-189" #25494 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020336000 nid=0x1f40 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000002eecd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault.get(OnHeapCachingTier.java:331)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault.access$200(OnHeapCachingTier.java:311)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier.getValue(OnHeapCachingTier.java:299)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier.get(OnHeapCachingTier.java:199)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore.get(CacheStore.java:192)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1751)
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.get(EhCacheCache.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:469)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:435)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:336)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:302)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:654)
    at com.xmgnss.service.UserBuslinesService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0f3eb42.select(<generated>)
    at com.xmgnss.controller.LastestGpsDataController.SelectLastestGpsData(LastestGpsDataController.java:294
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor380.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.xmgnss.filter.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    - locked <0x000000008c40c870> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x000000008b6443a0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

```
    - waiting to lock <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
    - locked <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000008b5e3bc8> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)

    Line 3187:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 3274:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 3361:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 3448:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 6984:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 7091:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 7404:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 7602:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 7915:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 8002:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 8089:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 8176:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 8485:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 8572:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 8841:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 9023:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 9292:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 9379:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 9692:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 9779:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 9866:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 10250:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 10428:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 10515:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 10602:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 10689:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 11049:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 11136:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 11223:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 11310:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 11397:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 11484:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 11571:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 11749:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 11927:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 12105:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 12192:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 12279:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 12366:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 12453:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 12540:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 12627:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 12714:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 13074:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 13161:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 13248:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 13335:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 13422:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 13509:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 13596:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 13683:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 14043:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 14130:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 14217:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 14304:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 14482:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 14569:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 14656:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 14834:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 14921:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15008:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15186:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15273:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15360:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15447:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15534:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15621:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15708:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15795:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15882:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 15969:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 16056:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 16234:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 16321:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 16408:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 16495:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 16582:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 16760:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 16847:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 16934:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17112:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17199:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17286:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17373:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17460:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17547:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17634:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17721:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17808:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17895:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 17982:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 18069:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 18247:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 18334:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 18421:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 18508:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 18595:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 18864:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 18951:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19038:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19125:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19212:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19299:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19386:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19473:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19560:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19647:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19734:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19821:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19908:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 19995:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 20082:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 20169:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 20256:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 20434:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 20521:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 20608:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 20695:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 20964:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 21051:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 21138:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 21225:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 21312:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 21399:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 21486:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 21573:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 21751:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 21838:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 21925:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 22107:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 22194:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 22281:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 22560:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 22647:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 22734:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 23012:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 23291:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 23378:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 23465:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 23738:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 24007:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 24190:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 24277:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 24364:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 24451:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 24538:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 24927:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 25014:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 25101:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 25188:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 25275:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 25457:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 25637:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 25910:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 25997:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 26084:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 26266:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 26353:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 26638:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 27048:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    Line 27231:    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
```

```
<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="D:/xiaoyuchuan/cache" />
    <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="1000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            overflowToDisk="false"/>
    <cache name="CarInfoTree"
           maxElementsOnDisk="0"
           maxElementsInMemory="20000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"/>
    <cache name="UserBuslines"
           maxElementsOnDisk="20000"
           maxElementsInMemory="2000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"/>
    <cache name="gnssData"
           maxElementsOnDisk="0"
           maxElementsInMemory="2000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"/>
</ehcache>
```

[The VisualVM Thread View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLtU7.jpg)

Comment: Can you include the `EhcacheUtil` code in your question ?

Comment: Sorry,i added the EncacheUtil,Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this problem,Ehcache is normal,it's our business code bug.
We use EhcacheUtil and Spring Ehcache annotation both, When EhcacheUtil return null,we will cyclic invocation out method,then The load on the server will suddenly increase, resulting in a description of the problem.

We solved this problem by only using Spring Ehcache annotation .